# Word that indicates that you played an important role, but were not the leader

Tags: verbs

Is there a word that is somewhere between "participated in" and "led?"

For example, last year my company created a new team and assigned me to lead it. I contributed significantly to the formation of the team, but I was not actually leading the effort to create it.

Comment: depends on how you define 'participated in' - a customer?

Comment: Leaders don't contribute.

Comment: @Jon Not a customer. Two senior staff members were doing most of the planning, but I had to be involved and provide feedback because it was eventually going to be my own team. Digging my own grave, if you will, but in the positive sense.

Comment: @Kris Not sure what you mean by that. I know the word "contribute" is usually reserved for individual contributors. Are you saying that is not how I should describe the role I had?

Comment: @Kris - A (good) leader certainly does contribute.

Comment: ELU frowns on long lists of words, so the following sentence makes a larger point about **participation on a team**. Depending on your specific contribution you:

affected,
advanced,
attended,
boosted,
drove,
caused,
commanded,
conducted,
contributed,
converted,
did,
directed,
encouraged,
executed,
furthered,
got,
guided,
helped,
induced,
introduced,
made,
managed,
motivated,
moved,
performed,
persuaded,
prevailed,
prompted,
promoted,
produced,
stimulated,
stood,
tended,
traveled, or ushered in a ***specific advantage*** for your new team, and you want them to know about it.

Comment: In a phrase: You were *delegated the task*.

Comment: @HotLicks That was a tongue in cheek comment, just fun.

Comment: @Kris - Fine.  I've certainly known "leaders" who did not contribute.  One manager in particular we worked hard to keep out of the engineering lab because he would always want to "help".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then you were a **key player**.

> one of the important people in a particular activity or field -[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/key-player)

Comment: It's not a verb, but I think it nicely conveys a notion between participating and leading.

Comment: If you want to get uppity about not getting a raise for your contribution (and probably get fired); you could say, "Had I not ***usurped*** the idiot in charge, this never would have got done". But, kiss your **employ**ment good-bye.

Answer (score 1):

**You played an "*integral*" role in the formation of the team**

> **integral** *adjective*: 1. necessary to make a whole complete; essential or fundamental. "games are an integral part of the school's curriculum"
>
> *synonyms*: essential, fundamental; Google [**integral**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=integral+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

**If "integral" lacks the prominence you seek to convey then, perhaps, "essential" is more serviceable:**

> **essential** *adjective*: 1. absolutely necessary; extremely important. "it is *essential* to keep up-to-date records"
>
> *synonyms*: crucial, necessary, *key*, vital, indispensable, important, ***critical***; Google [**essential**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=essential+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=essential+definition&gs_l=hp..1.0l5.0.0.0.7537...........0.hTDU9k012qE&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: "Integral" is good, but I don't think it conveys the sense of prominence I'm looking for. For example, nuts and bolts are integral to the building of a car, but marketing focuses on other parts.

Comment: I think "key" works well, and goes along with the accepted answer of "key player." Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

**senior** whatever:

senior team member

senior contributor

senior research staff